# How to check each element in an array if its prime or not

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to make program that prints out values form an array and that if they are or are not prime numbers. So far I have been able to make program which can take one value and print out if it's prime or not, however I haven't been able to implement this over to arrays. Here are my codes for printing out single numbers.

```
int isElementPrime(int value) {

if (0 == value % 2 || value < 2)
{
    printf_s("Number %d is not prime\n", value);
}

else
{
    printf_s("Number %d is prime\n", value);
}
return 0;


int main() {
int value = 4;
isElementPrime(value);
```

Output:

```
Number 4 is not prime
```

So the question is, how can this same thing be implemented to work with arrays?

**EDIT** As someone referred below, code is intended to only work up to number 8.

Comment: Through a `loop` over the array?

Comment: Just a side note: If a number is not dividable by 2 it does not mean that it is not a prime number. e.g. what about 3?

Comment: I think probably you need to use an algorithm for finding prime numbers. Personally I think the C++ tag is irrelevant.

Comment: According to your program, 9 (=3*3) is prime.

Comment: I do not think SO is a replacement for a textbook

Comment: _I have been able to make program which can take one value and print out if it's prime or not_ no, you have not.

Comment: @manni66 • The routine is accurate up-to-and-including 8.

Comment: @Eljay all negative numbers are prime here :(

Comment: @Slava • should be okay, since `value < 2` will be identified as not prime.

Comment: @Eljay is 1 considered a prime?

Comment: "code is intended to only work up to number 8." nice requirement, I wish I have such every day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want something as this?

```
int isElementPrime(int value) {

if (0 == value % 2 || value < 2)
{
    printf_s("Number %d is not prime\n", value);
}

else
{
    printf_s("Number %d is prime\n", value);
}
return 0;
}


int main() {
int values[4] = {1,2,3,4};
for(int i = 0; i < values.size();i++)
   isElementPrime(values[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple although inefficient way way to check if a number is prime is to loop through all of the whole integers from 2 up until the square root of the number in question and check if the loop counter (which will be between 2 and value exclusive) divides evenly into the tested value (with no remainder). This is a good place to start, you can then think about how to avoid unnecessary loop iterations.

Comment: "from 2 up until the number in question" it should be up to square root.